# Get real width of Android mobile device after orientationchange

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, width

It's really frustrating working with Android HTML5 and Javascript.

This time, I try to find out what current screen size (width) when DOM is loaded AND when the user changes orientation:

- **screen.width** works totally different on different AndroidOS-Versions. Impossible to use.
- jQuery's **$(window).width()** returns the real width but it fires before the orientation has changed. I tried it with a timeout of 200ms, doesn't work either.

Then I tried this snippet:

```
var deviceWidth = window.orientation == 0 ? window.screen.width : window.screen.height;

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0 && window.devicePixelRatio) {
  deviceWidth = deviceWidth / window.devicePixelRatio;
}
```

On some Android-Versions it changes by orientation, on some don't.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit / Solution:

That is how it worked for me on Android and iOS:

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  //console.log( "This device is in " + event.orientation + " mode!" );

  var oc_timer;
  clearTimeout(oc_timer);
  oc_timer = setTimeout(function () {
    //do your magic stuff with jQuery's $(window).width()
  }, 500);
);
$( window ).orientationchange(); //fire it manually on page load
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it inside the bind functions with timeout as below

```
  $(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
       var device_width = $(window).width();
     },500);
   });
```

Read more here : [Device and Viewport Size In JavaScript](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/)

> For
>
> - How to get viewport size
> - How to get device size.
> - How to get document size.

Also read: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp

Comment: Thanks! Watch at my solution in first post.

Answer (score 0):

This metod will get you the dimensions of your device :

```
Point size = new Point();
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height = 0;
int width = 0;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
} else {
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a Javascript-solution.